# Paper-ripple going all over screen instead of being contained within my element?

Tags: polymer

Am I doing something wrong here? For some reason my paper-ripple is happening when I click ***anywhere*** on the screen rather than just the image it's below? Did I mess up the syntax? The documentation isn't very clear..

```
<polymer-element name="sound-card">
<template>
    <style>
        /*snip*/
        .soundcard-img {
            height: 77%;
            width: 100%;
        }

        paper-ripple {
            color: #00ca92;
        }
    </style>
    <div class="soundcard-container" vertical layout>
        <img src="../img1.jpg" class="soundcard-img">
        <paper-ripple fit></paper-ripple>
        <div horizontal layout center justified>
            <div>test</div>
            <a href="#"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    Polymer({
        ready: function() {
        }
    });
</script>
</polymer-element>
```

Do I need to contain the paper-ripple in a polymer-defined element rather than a div? My container div is set at 200x260px, if that is relevant! Thanks!

Comment: Is it because you didn't close the `<polymer-element>` tag?

Comment: Ah sorry, didn't add the four spaces before it for stackoverflow. Nah, it's there! Good catch though :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at a web page inspector, the problem appears to be that the size of the `<paper-ripple>` element covers the whole page. Use of the `fit` attribute on that element [requires](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/polymer/layout-attrs.html#general-purpose-attributes):

> Note: When using the `fit` attribute, there must be a container with
>   fixed size and has `position: relative` layout. This is so the
>   children know where to fit to.

Adding `style="position:relative"` to your soundcard-container element (or any other way to add the style) does the trick for me on Chrome stable.